# Webpack 2 doesn't compile css inside of vue files

Tags: css, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, webpack-style-loader

Hello beautiful people,

I have a problem with compiling css for vue components. Here is my config file: https://gist.github.com/lavezzi1/27817a17cb4fa2a092e701089ecae0ec

I do multiple page app with vue. Everything works just fine except one thing: if I have two pages, and if they are both have imported modal `import Modal from 'components/modal.vue'` everything works fine, but if one haven't then the output .css file doesn't have css code for modal. How can I fix that?

My vue components look like:

```
<template>
...
</template>

<script>
...
</script>

<style lang="css">
   css here
</style>
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: are the CSS code added inline in the final JS bundle?

Comment: @DaniAkash no, I didn't find anything in output js bundle for the page that imported Modal. Just js, actually it works but without css.

Comment: add the css to your `main.js` like `require('path/to/css')` or use `style scoped` in the modal component.

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal which css?

Comment: `output.css` has the styles for the modal right?

Comment: looks like you have also tried extract-text-webpack-plugin, it didn't extract the CSS file?

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal No, thats why I posted this issue here. output.css doesn't contains css for modal. It contains only if both pages (entry files) imported modal.vue

Comment: @DaniAkash Nope, css output doesn't contains css for modal. It contains only if both pages (entry files) imported modal.vue

Comment: Is modal your own component?

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal I use this modal component https://github.com/JosephusPaye/Keen-UI/blob/master/src/UiModal.vue

Comment: Do you have `vue-template-compiler` in your project? Its needed to be fetched manually to work with webpack.

Comment: @magnudae yes I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should expand your vue-loader with options for compliling css.

For example:

```
  {
    test: /\.vue$/,
    loader: 'vue-loader',
    options: {
      loaders: {
        css: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
              options: {
                minimize: condition
              }
            }
          ],
          fallback: 'vue-style-loader'
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Webpack needs [vue-loader](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader) to handle Vue components.

Comment: Do you even saw my config? It does vue-loader, isn't?

Comment: I just saw `vue-style-loader`, my fault ;-)

Comment: it also has vue-loader